# Python Script Creating Binary File Instead of Folder in Google Drive

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

Title explains the bulk of it. This is supposed to create a new folder within a specified parent in my Google Drive but instead of creating a Google Drive Folder it's creating a binary file.

Everything else about it is working correctly: permissions, name, parent folder it's being created in but for some reason the mimetype isn't correct once it's created.

I'm going mad. I've triple checked the MIME type in the Drive API documentation and it's definitely right. I even watched [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/uI220BJ0yXc?t=221) where the same script is used (albeit in a for loop to create multiple files at once) and I get a different result.

What am I doing wrong?

```
def writeNewClientFolder():
   file_metadata = {
       'name': 'TESTFOLDER',
       'mimetype': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
       'parents': ['parentfolderID']
   }
   service.files().create(body=file_metadata).execute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the reason of your issue is due to the property name of `mimetype`. In this case, please modify it to `mimeType`. `T` of `Type` is the uppercase letter. I think that by `mimetype`, the file with the mimeType of `application/octet-stream` is created because the mimeType is not given. So please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
'mimetype': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
```

#### To:

```
'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
```

#### Reference:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)